# Error status after sending 32768 bytes from serial port in Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I am making uart communication using serial library. I can send and receive data, but when the number of bytes sent reaches 32768 or more, I get the error;

> ValueError: byte must be in range(0,256)

***function definition:***

```
def Write_to_serial_port(value):
    ser.write([value])
```

***function usage:***

```
#...
    for i in data_buf[0:total_len]:  # data_buf is a list
        Write_to_serial_port(i)  
#...
```

***The error message that occurs when the number of bytes sent reaches 32768:***
[image]

***An alternative serial port write function I tested:***

```
def Write_to_serial_port(value):
    data = struct.pack('>B', value)
    ser.write(data)
```

***Again the error message that occurs when the number of bytes sent reaches 32768:***
[image]

I also tried periodically flushing the input and output buffers, but it didn't help.
Any ideas on the solution?

***EDIT1:***
The purpose of the program is to send the bytes in the binary file. While doing this, I send 128 bytes (from the binary file) and 13 bytes of CRC, file size etc information over the serial port in each cycle. data_buff size is 255 bytes but I am using 141 bytes.

***function usage(Extended):***

```
# ...
# Some definitions and assignments
# ...

while(bytes_remaining):
    if(bytes_remaining >= 128):
        len_to_read = 128
    else:
        len_to_read = bytes_remaining

    for x in range(len_to_read):
        file_read_value = bin_file.read(1)
        data_buf[9+x] = int(file_read_value[0])

    data_buf[0] = mem_write_cmd_total_len-1
    data_buf[1] = write_cmd
    data_buf[2] = word_to_byte(base_mem_address,1,1)
    data_buf[3] = word_to_byte(base_mem_address,2,1)
    data_buf[4] = word_to_byte(base_mem_address,3,1)
    data_buf[5] = word_to_byte(base_mem_address,4,1)
    data_buf[6] = gl_bin_file_sector_needed
    data_buf[7] = len_to_read
    data_buf[8] = send_count
    send_count = send_count + 1

    crc32       = get_crc(data_buf,mem_write_cmd_total_len - 4)
    data_buf[9 +len_to_read] = word_to_byte(crc32,1,1)
    data_buf[10+len_to_read] = word_to_byte(crc32,2,1)
    data_buf[11+len_to_read] = word_to_byte(crc32,3,1)
    data_buf[12+len_to_read] = word_to_byte(crc32,4,1)

    for i in data_buf[0:mem_write_cmd_total_len]:
            Write_to_serial_port(i)

#...
```

***Error Message***
[image]

***EDIT2:*** I also tried splitting the 40KB binary file into 128byte chunk files and sending it. But I got the same error on the 256th file. I guess 256*128 = 32768 can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: I don't see how that error is related to the number of bytes being sent. More likely, `data_buf[i]` is a value greater than 255.

Comment: I've updated the post @chepner . I don't know why, but when I send less than 32768 bytes, no error occurs.

Comment: Have you done the simple step of `if data_buf[i] > 255:` / `print("Byte",i,"is too large")`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I did. When the number of sent bytes reached 32768, I saw that "data_buf[i] = 256".

Comment: Did you check the actual size of the file you are trying to read? Where do you get that size from? 32kb is often the size of an image for programming a microcontroller, and if you try to read past the end of file without checking something like this could occur.

Comment: @LevM. The file that I am trying to read is a 90 Kb binary file. I'm writing directly to the flash region of the MCU and my flash size is 1 Mb. So I don't think it will be a problem.

Comment: OK, but WHICH byte was 256?  That's the one you have to fix.

Comment: The focus should be on "When", not "Which". I tried to send different binary files, but when I try to send 32768. byte and after in all files, it gives an error. I don't have a problem with any of the smaller binaries. This cannot be a coincidence. Either the operating system has a buffering mechanism or there is a limitation in the pyserial library, but I couldn't understand what it was.